# How can I do python/ruby/javascript style generators in actionscript?

Tags: python, actionscript, generator, coroutine

I want to use coroutines in actionscript to implement a state machine.

I'd like to be able to do something like the following

```
function stateMachine():void
{
   sendBytes(0xFFFF);
   var receiveBytes:ByteArray = yield()
   sendBytes(receiveBytes);
}

stateMachine.send( Socket.read() )
```

like in this [blog entry](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/29/co-routines-as-an-alternative-to-state-machines/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Actionscript doesn't have coroutines, continuations or anything that will give you the relevant behavior (call a function without pushing a stack frame). You can fake it using static variables and a `switch`, but that defeats the purpose of using coroutines for state machines. Also, without tail calls (still only a [proposal for ECMASCRIPT](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=proposals:proper_tail_calls), as far as I know), faked coroutines won't use constant stack space as real coroutines do.

Regarding your sample code, coroutines generally need to loop to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about this?

```
function stateMachine(socket:Socket, target:YourReceiverClass):void
{
   target.sendBytes(0xFFFF);
   var receiveByte:int = socket.readByte();
   target.sendBytes(receiveByte);
}

stateMachine( mySocket )
```